# How to implement undo, redo and erase in Android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to create project like drawing which is needed to support drawing, undo, redo and eraser. Eraser must delete only for drawing view not delete background. Below code implements undo and redo functionality. I want to add eraser option but it's not done. How can implement eraser option using below code?

```
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.Canvas;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.Paint;
        import android.graphics.Path;
        import android.util.AttributeSet;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;


        import java.util.ArrayList;


        public class CanvasView extends View {


        private Paint mPenPainter;
        public int width;

        public int height;


        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;

        private Path mPath;

        Context context;

        private Paint mPaint;

        private float mX, mY;

        private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
        private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();


        private int paintColor = 0xFF000000;

        public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(c, attrs);

        context = c;


        // we set a new Path

        mPath = new Path();


        // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes

        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint.setColor(paintColor);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);


        //float mEraserWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.eraser_size);
        mPenPainter = new Paint();
        mPenPainter.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }


        // override onSizeChanged
        @Override

        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


        // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }


        // override onDraw

        @Override

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        for (Path p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // paths.add(mPath);

        }

        private void startTouch(float x, float y) {

        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

        mX = x;

        mY = y;
        }

        public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
        } else {
        //Util.Imageview_undo_redum_Status=false;
        }
        //toast the user
        }

        public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
        } else {
        // Util.Imageview_undo_redum_Status=false;
        }
        //toast the user
        }

        // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values

        private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);

        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {

        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);

        mX = x;

        mY = y;

        }
        }


        private void upTouch() {


        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath = new Path();
        }


        //override the onTouchEvent

        @Override

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();

        float y = event.getY();
        float mCurX;
        float mCurY;

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


        mX = event.getX();

        mY = event.getY();


        startTouch(x, y);
        invalidate();

        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


        moveTouch(x, y);

        invalidate();

        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        upTouch();
        invalidate();

        break;
        }

        return true;

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems a bit late answer but i finally made the solution after two days hardwork..

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;
    Boolean eraserOn = false;
    Boolean newAdded = false;
    Boolean allClear = false;
    private Path drawPath;

    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> undoBitmap = new ArrayList<>();

    public DrawView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        drawPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setDither(true);
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
     //   drawPaint.setAlpha(80);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        if(mBitmap==null) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // if(!eraserOn)
        canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
    }

    public void onClickEraser(boolean isEraserOn)
    {
        if (isEraserOn) {
            eraserOn = true;
            drawPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        }
        else {
            eraserOn = false;
            drawPaint.setColor(mPaint.getColor());
            drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        }
    }



    public void onClickUndo () {
        if(newAdded) {
            bitmap.add(mBitmap.copy(mBitmap.getConfig(), mBitmap.isMutable()));
            newAdded=false;
        }
        if (bitmap.size()>1)
        {
            undoBitmap.add(bitmap.remove(bitmap.size()-1));
            mBitmap= bitmap.get(bitmap.size()-1).copy(mBitmap.getConfig(),mBitmap.isMutable());
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            invalidate();
            if(bitmap.size()==1)
                allClear=true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
        //toast the user
    }

    public void onClickRedo (){
        if (undoBitmap.size()>0)
        {
            bitmap.add(undoBitmap.remove(undoBitmap.size()-1));
            mBitmap= bitmap.get(bitmap.size()-1).copy(mBitmap.getConfig(),mBitmap.isMutable());
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            invalidate();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        //toast the user
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        return super.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(penSelected || eraserSelected) {
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    newAdded = true;
                    if(!allClear)
                    bitmap.add(mBitmap.copy(mBitmap.getConfig(),mBitmap.isMutable()));
                    else allClear=false;

                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (eraserOn) {
                        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                        mCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                        drawPath.reset();
                        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    } else {
                        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                     drawPath.reset();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    return false;

                default:
                    return false;
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this class? please send me usage

Comment: Simply put this class where ever you want and set the variables according to your requirements

Comment: Excellent. This should be the accepted answer. Thank you @Usman Malik

Answer (score 2):

for erasing you need to find out intersect between current selection and draw paths. refer below code

```
   package opensourcecode.com.paginationwebview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by damodhar.meshram on 4/26/2017.
 */

public class CanvasView extends View {
    private Paint mPenPainter;
    public int width;

    public int height;


    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private Path mPath;

    Context context;

    private Paint mPaint;

    private float mX, mY;

    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    private boolean isErasemode = false;

    private int paintColor = 0xFF000000;

    public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(c, attrs);

        context = c;


        // we set a new Path

        mPath = new Path();


        // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes

        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint.setColor(paintColor);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);


        //float mEraserWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.eraser_size);
        mPenPainter = new Paint();
        mPenPainter.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }

    public CanvasView(Context c) {

        super(c);

        context = c;


        // we set a new Path

        mPath = new Path();


        // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes

        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint.setColor(paintColor);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);


        //float mEraserWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.eraser_size);
        mPenPainter = new Paint();
        mPenPainter.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }


    // override onSizeChanged
    @Override

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


        // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    }


    // override onDraw

    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // paths.add(mPath);

    }

    private void startTouch(float x, float y) {

        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

        mX = x;

        mY = y;
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {
            //Util.Imageview_undo_redum_Status=false;
        }
        //toast the user
    }

    public void onEraser(){
        if(!isErasemode){
            isErasemode = true;
        }else{
            isErasemode = false;
        }
    }

    private void remove(int index){
        paths.remove(index);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {
            // Util.Imageview_undo_redum_Status=false;
        }
        //toast the user
    }

    // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values

    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);

        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {

            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);

            mX = x;

            mY = y;

        }
    }


    private void upTouch() {


        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath = new Path();
    }


    //override the onTouchEvent

    @Override

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();

        float y = event.getY();
        float mCurX;
        float mCurY;

        if(isErasemode){

            for(int i = 0;i<paths.size();i++){
                RectF r = new RectF();
                Point pComp = new Point((int) (event.getX()), (int) (event.getY() ));

                Path mPath = paths.get(i);
                mPath.computeBounds(r, true);
                if (r.contains(pComp.x, pComp.y)) {
                    Log.i("need to remove","need to remove");
                    remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }else {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    mX = event.getX();

                    mY = event.getY();


                    startTouch(x, y);
                    invalidate();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                    moveTouch(x, y);

                    invalidate();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    upTouch();
                    invalidate();

                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy,Its working but user need to erase by touched position ,mean erase where ever swipe

Comment: Okey Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this pattern : 
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command

I used it to my application to use undo/redo

Comment: undo,reduo is working i need eraser option with same code